# Botão direcionando para pagina visitada

Tags: ionic, mobile, modal

Boa Tarde
Estou com um problema com ionic, Tenho um botao que esta direcionando para a minha Home Page. Sendo que quando eu direciono, a Home Page aparece como se eu ja estivesse visitado, aparece a setinha pra voltar. O que eu quero é que ela volte e comece a home zerada mesmo.

Meu template :

Encerrar Aplicativo

Seus Dados : </h3>
 Acertos : {{acertos}}   Erros : {{erros}}</h4>
Pontos: {{}}</h5> -->

Tem certeza que deseja Sair ?

Sim

Não

*Se você optar por sair, perderá todos os seus pontos e será 
  direcionado(a) para a pagina inicial.

Meu ts :

import { HomePage } from './../home/home';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ModalController, ViewController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';

/**
 * Generated class for the ModalfinalPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-modalfinal',
  templateUrl: 'modalfinal.html',
})
export class ModalfinalPage {

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
    public modalCtrl : ModalController,public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    public viewCtrl : ViewController) {
  }

public closeModal(){
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }

home(){
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
    }

ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ModalfinalPage');
  }

}

Answer (score 0):

tente ir para a pagina root, no lugar de:

```
home(){ this.navCtrl.push(HomePage); }
```

Tente:

```
   home(){ this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage); }
```